# Модуль email для kohana. Выдает ошибку при отправке письма

Tags: email, kohana

при регистрации пользователя, но его почту должно прийти сгенерированный пароль. Регистрация проходит, но отправка письма не идет, выдает ошибку.

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Kohana::config()
```

и в классе Email модуля email показывает эту строку

```
($config === NULL) and $config = Kohana::config('email');
```

в конфиг файле модуля все написал, работает через smpt, указал smpt.mail.ru, логин пароль и 25 порт. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Так то все правильно.

Comment: Какая разница, smtp или не smtp, когда у вас ошибка "вызов неопределенного метода"?

Answer (score 1):

Модуль от старой версии не обязательно будет подходить к новой. Гуглить по той самой строке, которую вам показывают.

Для ленивых, надо

```
($config === NULL) and $config = Kohana::config('email');
```

заменить на

```
($config === NULL) and $config = Kohana::$config->load('email');
```